# What do you call these types of windows?

Tags: word-request

[image: http://www.gettyimages.com/event/russias-opens-400th-kfc-fast-food-restaurant-559685859?esource=SEO_GIS_CDN_Redirect#-picture-id476804514]

What are they called? Wall windows?

Comment: Something like a window frame.

Comment: If you're refering to the size, they are: "full-length windows", "full-height windows" and "full-wall windows"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These large glass panels, that acts like a big screen to the outside, and are generally stationary (cannot be opened or moved) are collectively called ***stationary windows***.

They are also called ***picture windows*** or ***fixed windows***. The sole purpose of these glass panels are to provide people with a holistic view of the outside, which was originally made to face picturesque views of mountains or valleys or water bodies. In addition to all that, I also thing they are used to prevent people from feeling trapped or even [claustrophobic](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=claustrophobic&oq=claus&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.3560j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Here are some useful links that might come in handy for your research on the correct word.

- **[Fixed Window vs. Picture Window](http://en.jeld-wen.ca/blog/2014/06/26/what-is-the-difference-between-a-picture-and-fixed-window/)**
- **[Types of windows](http://www.hgtv.com/remodel/interior-remodel/8-types-of-windows-pictures)**
- **[Home window types](https://modernize.com/windows/types)**

Comment: I have never heard the term "stationary windows".

Comment: @ColinFine, you learn new things everyday. This is one of those things. **[Stationary Windows](http://www.windowsandsiding.net/windows/faq/what-is-a-stationary-window/)**

Comment: Evidently, Varun KN. I wondered if this might be a UK/US thing so I looked on a couple of corpora. Among the ten different English Corpora on the BYU site (between 50 million and 1.9 billion words) there is precisely one instance of "stationary window" (and none of "stationary windows") - and that is talking about a computer window. I can't account for why they don't appear in any of the corpora, since you have given me an example, and a search shows more. But it looks to me that nobody besides the window trade uses the phrase.

Comment: I think usage notes like the ones @Colin mentions are indispensable. It’s one thing to say, “This is called a stationary window,” but I wouldn’t want our site to send learners out there with a new phrase that’s only going to get them puzzled looks. Whether a phrase is little-known parlance or common in the vernacular makes a difference, and a good answer will say which is the case.

Answer (score 1):

In Britain these are called [*Plate Glass Windows*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&q=plate+glass+window).

This is because they are made of plate glass - which is a technique for manufacturing large sheets of glass.

Any large glass frontage of a shop or restaurant like this is referred to as Plate Glass.